# Why is my visual studio executing old code?

Tags: c++

Am wrriting a cpp code while testing and debugging it, but once i run it to debug and make changes to the code , the program still executes the old code block.

Am attempting to write  code blocks while debugging and make changes to them as i continue coding.

Comment: try doing a clean and rebuild?

Comment: [Visual Studio 2019 Always run OLD version code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537050/visual-studio-2019-always-run-old-version-code) and [Visual Studio keeps running the old build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699418/visual-studio-keeps-running-the-old-build) and [Why is Visual Studio Code Running Old Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297180/why-is-visual-studio-code-running-old-code)

Comment: See [C in Visual Studio 2013, why is previously executed code which is now in comment still executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846668/c-in-visual-studio-2013-why-is-previously-executed-code-which-is-now-in-comment) which says clean and rebuild.

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio or VSCode. These are 2 completely different products with a similar name. Because the latter may require (depending on your settings) that you save your file before you press the debug button.

Comment: More often than not, on SO, it's because OP isn't saving their changes.